# C# Covariance in Classes Implementing Common Interface

Tags: c#, covariance

A WPF program I'm writing in C# has the following interface on the back-end:

```
public interface CatalogMenu<T> : CatalogItem where T : CatalogItem
{
    void AddCatalogItem(T toAdd);
    void RemoveCatalogItem(T toRemove);

    List<T> AvailableCatalogItems { get; }
}
```

I have three classes that implement the interface, each with a different T.  The problem is that I want to create a `List<CatalogMenu<CatalogItem>>` to bind to a ListView, but this property in the View-Model doesn't compile... (thing1, thing2, and thing3 all implement the interface with a different T)

```
public List<CatalogMenu<CatalogItem>> MenuCategories
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<CatalogMenu<CatalogItem>>(){
                ModuleCatalog.thing1, 
                ModuleCatalog.thing2, 
                ModuleCatalog.thing3 
            };
        }
    }
```

As much as I'd like it to, the compiler won't let me treat the "classes implementing `CatalogMenu<T>` where T is a CatalogEntity" as a "`CatalogMenu<CatalogItem>`".  I want to present each class implementing the interface to the user through a common interface.

If I left out any details, be a little patient with me; my head's spaghetti after reading about covariance for the last 30 minutes in an attempt to figure out a way to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried simply casting? `return new List<bla>() { (CatalogMenu<CatalogItem>)ModuleCatalog.ting1 }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net does not support covariant *classes*.

If you add an `ICatalogMenu<out T>`, you will be able to cast any CatalogMenu to `ICatalogMenu<CatalogItem>` and put it into a `List<ICatalogMenu<CatalogItem>>`

You can accomplish the same effect using an ordinary non-generic interface or base class.

Comment: The out parameter allows me to cast the ICatalogMenu to ICatalogMenu<CatalogItem>, but I can't use the type parameter as a method argument in the add and remove methods, and a lot of my code depends on those two methods.  I'd like to use a non-generic interface, but using one makes serializing the objects according to their specific types easier elsewhere in the code.  Basically, if I don't use the generic classes, I have to rewrite most of the program at this point :(

Comment: @Quanta: If your type parameter is used as an argument type, what your trying to do is actually not type-safe.